# Usar select2 con datos cargados previamente con ajax en ventana modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, select2

Tengo una ventana modal la cual tiene un select, los datos de esta son cargados mediante ajax

Importo select2

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

A continuacion el codigo HTML de la ventana modal

```
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="color" class="modal-header bg-gradient-success">
                <h5 id="modalTitle" class="modal-title">Nuevo(s) Ejemplar</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close btnCerrar" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">
                        ×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="frmEjemplar">
                    @csrf
                    <input id="metodo" type="hidden" name="_method">
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='recurso_id' class='col-form-label'>Recursos</label>
                        <select id="recurso_id" name="recurso_id"
                            class="form-select block w-full mt-1 rounded border-gray-300 select2" required></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='observaciones' class='col-form-label'>Observaciones</label>
                        <textarea id='observaciones' name='observaciones' type='text' class='form-control'></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='fecha_adquisicion' class='col-form-label'>Fecha de adquisición</label>
                        <input id='fecha_adquisicion' name='fecha_adquisicion' type='date' class='form-control'
                            required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btnCerrar font-weight-bold" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                        <button id="btnCrear" type="submit" class="btn btn-success font-weight-bold"
                            data-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        ...
        $('#recurso_id').append(
                    `<option value="" hidden>Seleccione un recurso</option>`);
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'ejemplares/create',
                    success: function(response) {
                        let response = JSON.parse(response);
                        response.forEach(element => {
                            for (let i = 0, l = element.recursos.length; i < l; i++) {
                                $('#recurso_id').append(
                                    `<option value="${element.recursos[i].id}">${element.recursos[i].nombre}</option>`
                                );       
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
         $('.select2').select2();

});
```

El codigo ajax funciona bien sin usar select2 me carga todos los elementos, pero si trato de usar el select2 no me carga ninguno solo aparece la opcion default.

La idea seria que me carguen todos los registros pero que pueda buscar el que necesito.

Comment: Cuando quieres activar el _select_ aún no existe. Mueve esta línea `$('.select2').select2();` debajo de la llave de cierre del `for` y debería funcionar.

Comment: @triby todavia me sale lo mismo, no me carga lo que me trae el ajax

Comment: añadiendo el parametro dropdownParent si funciona pero pierde el diseño del bootstrap, alguna forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: Ya quedo solucionado, gracias por la ayuda, con su orientación me pude guiar y encontrar la solución definitiva.